VSCode Jupyter Notebook Markdown display two layers of text overlapping each other
I have been using VSCode Jupyter Notebook for coding.
Recently when I open an .ipynb file, the markdown shows "ghosting", which means two layers of text overlapping each other.
It only happened in this file so far, I have no clue why it is happening.
enter image description here

Version:1.88.1, Electron:28.2.8, Chromium:120.0.6099.291, OS:Windows_NT x64 10.0.19041

what if you update to the latest version of VS Code and the jupyter extensions?
